# Integrating factor for an ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

our teacher had asked a question in final exam and i did something and sent him. but my solution graded 0. so i have the question you may help me. i really appreciate your help.

$$ xdy -(x^2+y^2+y)dx = 0 $$ eq is given.

$$ \mu = (x^2+y^2)^\Omega $$  and this is the integration constant that makes the differential equation exact differential equation.

the question what is omega.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ODE $Mdx+Ndy=0$ is exact if $\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}$
The given ODE
$$-(x^2+y^2+y)dx+xdy=0~~~~(1)$$
is not exact, but if we multiply by $\mu=(x^2+y^2)^{-1}$
We get $$-(1+\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}) dx+\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}dy=0 ~~~~(2)$$
Then it becomes exact as
$$\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}=\frac{y^2-x^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$$
Then the solution of (1) or (2) is written as
$$\int -(1+\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}) dx ~~\text{(treat $y$ as constant)}+ \int 0 dy=C$$
$$\implies x+\tan^{-1}\frac{y}{x}=C$$
So inthe integrating factor $\mu$, $\Omega=-1$

**For OP:** Take $\mu=(x^2+y^2)^\Omega$ and multiply it to (1)
The new $N$ and $M$ are
$$M=-(x^2+y^2)^\Omega (x^2+y^2+y),~~ N=x(x^2+y^2)^\Omega$$
Then $$\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}=(x^2+y^2)^{\Omega-1}[-(\Omega+1)(x^2+y^2)2y-x^2-y^2+2y^2]~~~~(3)$$
$$\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}=(x^2+y^2)^{\Omega-1}(x^2+y^2+2\Omega x^2]~~~~(4)$$
Check $\Omega=-1$, makes (3) and (2) identical.

Comment: How did you find that omega is -1

Comment: Sir please give me more information about how did you find that omega is -1 or did you just predict it. Please let me know.

Comment: @Little Prince You may see my edit.